# How do I load a Vue plugin when loading Vue asyncronously?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I'm a bit new to using vue and webpack, and I'm trying to set up a form component. I'm getting an error saying "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Vue.use is not a function". The code that I am using is a modification of the code here: https://auralinna.blog/post/2018/how-to-build-a-complete-form-with-vue-js

I am loading Vue into my app asynchronously, so I think the issue may be that Vue isn't loaded yet, but I don't know enough to say for sure.

Here's my main app.js file:

```
// App main
const main = async () => {
// Import our CSS
//const Styles = await import(/* webpackChunkName: "styles" */ '../css/app.pcss');
// Async load the vue module
const Vue = await import(/* webpackChunkName: "vue" */ 'vue');
const VueI18n = await import(/* webpackChunkName: "vue-i18n" */ 'vue-i18n');
const Vuelidate = await import(/* webpackChunkName: "vuelidate" */ 'vuelidate');
const translations = await import(/* webpackChunkName: "translations" */ '../resources/translations');
const Scrollmagic = await import(/* webpackChunkName: "scrollmagic" */ 'scrollmagic');

Vue.use(VueI18n);
Vue.use(Vuelidate);

const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    messages: translations
})

// process layout images



// Create our vue instance
const vm = new Vue.default({
    el: "#app",
    i18n,
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    components: {
        'carousel': () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "vue-owl-carousel-br" */ '../vue/vue-owl-carousel-br/src/Carousel.vue'),
        'appForm': () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "app-form" */ '../vue/form/form.vue'),
    },
    data: {
        menuActive: false,
        footerActive: false,
    },
    methods: {

    },
    mounted() {
    },
});
};
```

The error message in the console says "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Vue.use is not a function" and it is happening at line 14: Vue.use(VueI18n);

I'm trying to resolve the error so that hopefully the form component will render. Can anyone point me to what I need to adjust to resolve this problem?

Comment: Instead of `const Vue = await import(/* webpackChunkName: "vue" */ 'vue');` I would just write `import Vue from 'vue'`. Same for other imports

Comment: Chunking is useful with vue-router, where you can tell router to lazy-load components when needed. I'm not sure there is any benefit of doing that in `app.js`.